# rails crud using jquery popover via bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to add jquery popover to rails default cruds instead of redireting to views and what I am doing is rendering the form in the jquery popover:

```
<%= content_tag_for :tr, @order.order_items do |i| %>
<a class='btn btn-mini label-with-popover' id=<%=i.id%>><%= t('helpers.links.edit_html') %> </a>
<% end %>    

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('.label-with-popover').popover({ 
        html : true,
        content: "<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form_item') %>" , 
        placement:  'top'
      } );
    });
    </script>
```

and here is my form_item:

```
<%= simple_form_for :order_item, url:  admin_shop_order_path,  :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class='form-inputs'>
    <%= f.input :item_id , :collection => @shop.products.collect{|b| b.variants}.flatten.map{|variant| ["#{variant_full_title(variant)}", variant.id]}%> 
    <%= f.input :quantity %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t("helpers.links.cancel"), admin_shop_orders_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

but the problem appears on the edit button. to render the edit form we need the object that we want to edit(:order_item I mean) and a way to get that is by using the id and this is why I have set the anchor tag id. now we have to get that anchor id within the popover function but $(this).id doesn't work. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, you need to use attr('id') to get the id of an element. Try to replace $(this).id with:

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

See jQuery's documentation for more details: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

But a prefered way to achieve this is usually to use data attributes. It's a clean way to pass data from your view to some JS code. Your link would look like this:

```
<a class='btn btn-mini label-with-popover' data-item-id=<%=i.id%>>...</a>
```

And in your JS file, you would get this value using:

```
$(this).data('item-id')
```

jQuery's documentation: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Yeah tnx but there is still a problem. We can't use that line in the erb tag like this : "<%=" + "escape_javascript .... ( your code ) " + "%>" . that doesn't work. we are in erb file. every <%= translates to ruby code and if we use "\<\%\=" then it doesn't execute as a ruby code.

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Can you update your question to include the code from the erb?

Comment: In that case you need indeed to pass the id to the partial, as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering wrongly, I think, you should try to render your partial with locals. You can also pass local variables into partials, making them even more powerful and flexible.

In your case, while rendering your partial `form_item` in script tag, so you can write it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('.label-with-popover').popover({ 
        html : true,
        content: "<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form_item', :locals => {order_item: @order_item}) %>" , 
        placement:  'top'
      } );
    });
    </script>
```

and in your form you will be able to access it like :

```
<%= form_for(order_item) do %>

 # write your form stuff %>

<% end %>
```

This way you can handle your form for both create or edit operations.

First I suggest you to pass id with some text added to it(I replaced the id with `"link_<%= i.id%>")`.
Second call a onclick function on your a tag:

```
<%= content_tag_for :tr, @order.order_items do |i| %>
<a class='btn btn-mini label-with-popover' id="link_<%=i.id%>" ><%= t('helpers.links.edit_html') onclick="javascript:openPopup(this.id)" %> </a>
<% end %>
```

and Last but not the least, get id in your function, and pass it through your partial.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openPopup(a_id) {
      var id = a_id.split("link_")[1];
      $('.label-with-popover').popover({ 
        html : true,
        content: "<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form_item', locals => {:id => id}) %>" , 
        placement:  'top'
      } );
    });
    </script>
```

I am not good at javascript, but from my answer, you will get, what I wanted to explain you. and I am sure that you will find a more improved way to do this. And If you do, please post it here as well. Hope it will help. Thanks

Comment: Yes I had thought about local variables but I didn't mention it in the question but still we have the problem. where do you want to set @order_item? there are bunch of them and I have to get ids from anchors.

Comment: I will surely help you. Give me 5 minutes. have to look into jQuery popover library once.

Comment: tnx again bro but "id" in the locals doesn't change to its value as we got it by javascript. because it is in double quotation.

Comment: Ohh..How did I miss that? 
content takes string as a parameter, May be it work:
content: "<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form_item', locals => {:id => " + id + "}) %>"

Comment: welcome to the new problem I'm dealing with :D I ran into this problems several hours ago :D the problem is that "<%= something" + FooBar + " %>" doesn't work. we are in an erb file and everything after <%= or before %> translates to ruby code. maybe you say try "\<\%\=" but that doesn't work too! :D by doing this, your rendering code never works :D <%= tag looses its effect.

Comment: you are writing this script in a view or a helper?

Comment: we are using erb tags so we are in a view ;)

Comment: forget about stack overflow chat :D let's discuss here.